# Hybrid Remote App with Offline storage

Tags: mobilesdk, offline, smartstore, hybrid-remote

I am new to salesforce development and i want to deploy a hybrid remote application that can store the data when offline and den again update with the server once it is back online.

I understand that this question has been asked in a different way but without a concrete answer.
Anyone can give a detailed description about how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

[Old question but I'm answering anyway just in case it helps]

The Force.com Mobile SDK provides a framework called SmartSync which allows you to sync data back to Saelsforce once Internet connectivity is restored. You can read more about it on the Mobile SDK github repos for [Android](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Android) and [iOS](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS)

Look at the [SimpleSync](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Android/tree/master/hybrid/SampleApps/SimpleSync) app to see how the syncing actually works. Hope this helps.